# Testing Spring webflux complain about "Unfinished Step Verifier". Ho finish the test properly and fully?

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-test

I am using SpringWebflux to playground some tests.

I am getting one highlight in IDE, saing "Unfinished Step Verifier"

Thats my code:

```
    @Test
    public void findAllNextMatches() {
        StepVerifier
                .create(repo.findAll())
                .expectNextMatches(u -> u.getId()
                                         .equals(cust1.getId()))
                .expectComplete();
    }
```

The IntellijIdea Highlight "expectComplete", and complain saying: "Unfinished Step Verifier".

How Can I finish the test properly , in order to avoid, the complaiment above?

Thanks a lot, in advance

Answer (score 3):

Add at the end

```
   .verify();
```

Source: https://projectreactor.io/docs/test/release/api/index.html?reactor/test/StepVerifier.html

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to use the `verifyComplete()` instead of the simple `verify()`, because you can avoid the `.expectComplete()` since you know that the test must return something.

I use `verify()` when the test must NOT return any value but I need to execute the Flux.

The [docs](https://projectreactor.io/docs/test/release/api/reactor/test/StepVerifier.LastStep.html#verifyComplete--) also suggest

> This is a convenience method that calls StepVerifier.verify() in addition to the expectation.